# Find and update many documents listed in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to update my database by finding all documents that are matched listed in an array, then update the multiple documents that are listed, I was able to update a single document using `findOne()` but when I use `find()` to look for all documents that are matched in the array.. it doesn't update. Any solution for this?

**Sample documents:**

```
_id:5c5ef16221a4961b68e64d98
serial_code:"one"
status:"available"

_id:5c5ef17541a4961b68e64d98
serial_code:"two"
status:"available"
```

**My Code:**

```
Bloodstock.find({ serial_code : { $in : ['one','two','three'] } }, function(bloodstock) {                                               
    bloodstock.status = 'not available';                            
    bloodstock.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err); 
        } else {
            console.log('success'); 
        }
    });  
});
```

**Gives me err:**

> `TypeError: bloodstock.save is not a function`

Comment: handle err in your callback

Comment: `bloodstock` is an array not an object. You have to itrate over the `bloodstock` and then need to save one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose's callbacks typically take two arguments and first one represents and error, take a look [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find). Therefore your code could look like below:

```
Bloodstock.find({ serial_code : { $in : ['one','two','three'] } }, function(error, bloodstockDocs) {                                               
    if(error) return;
    for(let bloodstock of bloodstockDocs) {
        bloodstock.status = 'not available';                            
        bloodstock.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err); 
            } else {
                console.log('success'); 
            }
        });
    }  
});
```

EDIT: `find` returns a collection so you need to use `for` loop to iterate through those documents.

Comment: still gives me TypeError: bloodstock.save is not a function

Comment: @JeremyAdriandeVera modified my answer

Answer (score 3):

Use update query instead

```
Bloodstock.update(
  { serial_code : { $in : ['one','two','three'] } },
  { $set: { status: 'not available' }}, 
  { multi: true },
  function (err, result){
    console.log(result)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update method with option **multi: true** to update multiple document that match your query.

```
Bloodstock.update(
  { serial_code : { $in : ['one','two','three'] } },
  { $set: { status: 'not available' }}, 
  { multi: true },
  function (err, result){
    console.log(result)
  }
);
```

You can check more details about options here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/